# how to declare object class inside a class(scala code) in java

Tags: java, scala, class, object

I have this class in scala:

```
class AuthResponse(  val ip: String,
                         val authorized: Boolean,
                         val sid: String,
                         val uid: String,
                         val ratio: Double,
                         val skipRecording: Boolean,
                         val rejectReason: String,
                         val userTrackingState: String,
                         val pid: Int = conf.getString(s"WebRecorder.Environments.${conf.getString("WebRecorder.Current.Environment")}.Pid").toInt) {
      // If we write val before input vars it constract the same values

      //Override toString method
      override def toString: String = {
            "ip: " + ip + "\n" +
            "authorized: " + authorized + "\n" +
            "sid: " + sid + "\n" +
            "uid: " + uid + "\n" +
            "ratio: " + ratio + "\n" +
            "skipRecording: " + skipRecording + "\n" +
            "rejectReason: " + rejectReason + "\n" +
              "pid: " + pid + "\n" +
            "userTrackingState: " + userTrackingState
      }
    }

    object AuthResponse {

      def apply(ip: String, authorized: Boolean, sid: String, uid: String, ratio: Double, skipRecording: Boolean, rejectReason: String, userTrackingState: String): AuthResponse =
        new AuthResponse(ip, authorized, sid, uid, ratio, skipRecording, rejectReason, userTrackingState)

      def apply(responseAsJson: String): AuthResponse =  {
        new Gson().fromJson(responseAsJson, classOf[AuthResponse])
      }
    }
```

I am trying to make it java code as follow:

```
public class AuthResponse {

String ip;
Boolean authorized;
String sid;
String uid;
Double ratio;
Boolean skipRecording;
String rejectReason;
String userTrackingState;
int pid = Integer.parseInt(Configuration.prop.getProperty(""));

@Override
public String toString(){
   return
   ("ip: " + ip + "\n" +
    "authorized: " + authorized + "\n" +
    "sid: " + sid + "\n" +
    "uid: " + uid + "\n" +
    "ratio: " + ratio + "\n" +
    "skipRecording: " + skipRecording + "\n" +
    "rejectReason: " + rejectReason + "\n" +
    "pid: " + pid + "\n" +
    "userTrackingState: " + userTrackingState + "\n");
}

    class AuthResponse(){

        public AuthResponse apply(String ip,boolean authorized, String sid,String uid, double ratio,boolean skipRecording, String rejectReason, String userTrackingState){
           return new AuthResponse(ip,authorized,sid,uid,ratio,skipRecording,rejectReason,userTrackingState);
        }

        public com.pipe.pipeapp.AuthResponse apply(String responseAsJson){
            return new
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to see how i can implment another class inside my class with the same name as for scala we can use object and class and it is completely different classes (since it is not class but object) but in Java we cannot do that, how can I implement the same class including object class in java?

Answer (score 1):

Scala `object` might be compiled into different things depending on what's inside. In your case `object AuthResponse` is actually compiled in something that is similar to Java `static` methods on the `class AuthResponse` itself. So it would be something like this:

```
public class AuthResponse {

    public final String ip;
    public final Boolean authorized;
    public final String sid;
    public final String uid;
    public final Double ratio;
    public final Boolean skipRecording;
    public final String rejectReason;
    public final String userTrackingState;
    public final int pid;


    public AuthResponse(String ip, Boolean authorized, String sid, String uid, Double ratio, Boolean skipRecording, String rejectReason, String userTrackingState, int pid) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.authorized = authorized;
        this.sid = sid;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.ratio = ratio;
        this.skipRecording = skipRecording;
        this.rejectReason = rejectReason;
        this.userTrackingState = userTrackingState;
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public AuthResponse(String ip, Boolean authorized, String sid, String uid, Double ratio, Boolean skipRecording, String rejectReason, String userTrackingState) {
        this(ip, authorized, sid, uid, ratio, skipRecording, rejectReason, userTrackingState, Integer.parseInt(Configuration.prop.getProperty("")));
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                ("ip: " + ip + "\n" +
                        "authorized: " + authorized + "\n" +
                        "sid: " + sid + "\n" +
                        "uid: " + uid + "\n" +
                        "ratio: " + ratio + "\n" +
                        "skipRecording: " + skipRecording + "\n" +
                        "rejectReason: " + rejectReason + "\n" +
                        "pid: " + pid + "\n" +
                        "userTrackingState: " + userTrackingState + "\n");
    }

    public static AuthResponse apply(String ip, boolean authorized, String sid, String uid, double ratio,
                                     boolean skipRecording, String rejectReason, String userTrackingState) {
        return new AuthResponse(ip, authorized, sid, uid, ratio, skipRecording, rejectReason, userTrackingState);
    }

    public static AuthResponse apply(String responseAsJson) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(responseAsJson, AuthResponse.class);
    }
}
```

Although going to Java I would rename `apply` methods to something more meaningful such as `create`. Also you may introduce getters for fields instead of making them just public but I didn't bother to make the code shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I let you documentation that can help in that case [Nested Classes Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). Here explain when use nested classes [When to Use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your answer to include a summary of the solution your links suggest, so your answer doesn't succumb to link rot.

Comment: so you say in general that the above code of scala is actually nested classes in java?

Comment: Not in general but there are many different ways to do. You can use nested classes to represent the structure exactly  or use the SergGr answer with constructors. You can also use ID's like IntelliJ that transform scala to java code automatically. Maybe in java is more easier to understand the SergGr option.